# Resolve URL with info from URL parameters

Tags: node.js, express

I've been thrown at a Node.js project at work and I'm not a Node developer.  My first task is to resolve urls to stores from a URL parameter.  Here's what needs to happen:

The original URL contains the URL parameter "siteName" as here:

https://example.com/s/Store/?siteName=SLUG

The above url with parameter would then resolve to

https://example.com/s/Store/SLUG

This project is running on Express ^4.3.0.

I've been diving into the Node docs but I'm not sure even where to start.

Comment: Surely this is a matter of just adding a redirect middleware based on what you find in [req.originalUrl](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.originalUrl) as part of the `app.get("Store", ...)` chain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you look into [Express](https://expressjs.com/)

The solution to your problem is easy. Firstly, you'd need to establish a middleware to listen to requests for /s/Stores route. Then parse the query params and get the value for the siteName key. Finally use the res.redirect method to run the logic for /s/Store/SLUG route.

The solution would look something like

```
app.get('/s/Stores', (req, res, next) => {
  const query = req.query;
  const siteName = query.siteName;

  res.redirect('/s/Stores/' + siteName);
});

app.get('/s/Stores/:siteName', (req, res, next) => {
  const siteName = req.params.siteName;

  if (siteName === 'SLUG') {
    // do something
  }

  // do something else
});
```

Comment: This project is running on Express ^4.3.0.

Comment: The solution is for express @mediaguru. I just said look into express documentation to gain some insight about how req and res objects work here.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `Store` route is the page you want to see with parameters, if you are using url query parameters, use first example and it matches your first question.

If you are trying to get url parameters without query, use second example.

```
//https://example.com/s/Store/?siteName=SLUG

app.get('/Store', function(req, res){
  let siteName = req.query.siteName,
});

//https://example.com/s/Store/SLUG/
app.get('/Store/:slug', function (req, res) {
   let slug = req.params.slug,
});
```

Comment: Pardon my lack of node/express knowledge, but can I assume this goes in the entrypoint, as in index.js?

Comment: @mediaguru Do you have your router set up ?

Comment: I believe it is.  If I run the code below the log works as expected. There are also some app.use statements in the index.js file. 

        app.get('/', function (req, res) {
          console.log('hello');
        })

Comment: Okay nice, put my code in your index.js and try. If anything unexpected happens, let me know so we can find a solution.